# Problem with date formatting

Tags: i18n-l10n, datetime

I've a strange problem with Date formatting in Chinese.

[image]

The **年** string has to appear after year(for example 2013年). The string appears in all years before 2013 and also in 2013. But if it is future year(2014, 2015 etc) then it doesn't appear.

This is the date format used.

```
Y\年 n\月 j\日
```

I am not sure if it is Drupal's problem or PHP's. And I have no clue how to debug this issue. Any kind of hint is most welcome.

Comment: This unusual, you say  your character appear in 2013 but notshow in futures years?

Comment: Yes this is very unusual. The character does not appear in  years like 2014, 2015, 2016 and so on.  But it appears fine in 2010, 2011, 2012 and 2013.

Comment: Do u test another characters (latin chars) ? Is this problem exist only for your character or it is for all character ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know really why but I have a solution for you 
first put you result in a variable, ( try you result something like this Y/n/j )
then exclude variable by `/` and finally use your character.

```
$temp=date('Y/n/j');
list($y,$n,$j)=exclude('\/',$temp);
$final="$y\年 $n\月 $j\日";
```

I hope be useful for you. :)